# How get item in HTMLCollection?

Tags: magento2, javascript

I have code:

```
let fieldset = document.getElementsByClassName('fieldset-wrapper');

            console.log(fieldset);
```

in console log:

> ```
> HTMLCollection { length: 0 }
> ```

when I open collection in console log:

```
HTMLCollection
​
0: <div class="fieldset-wrapper" data-bind="visible: $data.visible =…l, 'data-index': index}" data-level="0" data-index="general">​
1: <div class="fieldset-wrapper" data-bind="visible: $data.visible =…l, 'data-index': index}" data-level="0" data-index="options_container">
​
length: 2
```

But when I try to:

```
console.log(fieldset[0]);
```

I got an answer 'undefined';
How do I get items from a collection? thanks for the answer

Comment: How is your HTML added? It sounds like it is being injected by JS?

Comment: @BenCrook I added thanks to the Ui component